# My project doesn't switch between two different tracking algorithms

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am trying to track an object with opencv in C++ in 2 methods.the first method is with absolute difference alghorithm and the second method is tracking with color using dilate and erode that both of them work perfectly.when you press "t" on the keyboard it will use the absdiff algorithm and tracks the object.when you press "t" again it will stop the tracking but when i press "p" on the keyboard for using the dilate and erode method it starts tracking the ROI area but it doesnt break out of the method when i press "p" again and i cant go back to using absdiff method

```
     #include <opencv\cv.h>
        #include <opencv\highgui.h>
        #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
        #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
        #include <iostream>
        #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

        using namespace cv;
        using namespace std;

        //our sensitivity value to be used in the absdiff() function
        const static int SENSITIVITY_VALUE = 20;
        //size of blur used to smooth the intensity image output from absdiff() function
        const static int BLUR_SIZE = 10;
           //we'll have just one object to search for
        //and keep track of its position.
        int theObject[2] = { 0,0 };
        //bounding rectangle of the object, we will use the center of this as its position.
        Rect objectBoundingRectangle = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

        int H_MIN = 0;
        int H_MAX = 256;
        int S_MIN = 0;
        int S_MAX = 256;
        int V_MIN = 0;
        int V_MAX = 256;

        const string windowName = "Original Image";
        const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
        const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
        const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
        const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";

        void on_trackbar( int, void* )
    {//This function gets called whenever a
        // trackbar position is changed





    }
    string intToString(int number){


        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << number;
        return ss.str();
    }
    void createTrackbars(){
        //create window for trackbars


        namedWindow(trackbarWindowName,0);
        //create memory to store trackbar name on window
        char TrackbarName[50];
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
        sprintf( TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX);
        //create trackbars and insert them into window
        //3 parameters are: the address of the variable that is changing when the trackbar is moved(eg.H_LOW),
        //the max value the trackbar can move (eg. H_HIGH), 
        //and the function that is called whenever the trackbar is moved(eg. on_trackbar)
        //                                  ---->    ---->     ---->      
        createTrackbar( "H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
        createTrackbar( "H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar );
        createTrackbar( "S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
        createTrackbar( "S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar );
        createTrackbar( "V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar );
        createTrackbar( "V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar );


    }
        void morphOps(Mat &thresh) {

            //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
            //the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle

            Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3));
            //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
            Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8, 8));

            erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);
            erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);

            dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);
            dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);

        }
        void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed) {

            Mat temp;
            threshold.copyTo(temp);
            //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
            vector< vector<Point> > contours;
            vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
            //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
            findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            bool objectFound = false;
            if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
                int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
                //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
            }
            int maxX = 0, minX = cameraFeed.cols, maxY = 0, minY = cameraFeed.rows;

            for (int i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
                {
                    Point p = contours[i][j];

                    maxX = max(maxX, p.x);
                    minX = min(minX, p.x);

                    maxY = max(maxY, p.y);
                    minY = min(minY, p.y);
                }

            rectangle(cameraFeed, Point(minX, minY), Point(maxX, maxY), Scalar(0));
            //find center of the rectangle
            int m = minX + maxX / 4;
            int m2 = minY + maxY / 4;
            //calculate the arc tangent

            double angle;
            angle = atan(m / m2);
            //draw the circle
            circle(cameraFeed, Point(m, m2), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, 0);
        }

        void searchForMovement(Mat thresholdImage, Mat &cameraFeed){
    //notice how we use the '&' operator for objectDetected and cameraFeed. This is because we wish
    //to take the values passed into the function and manipulate them, rather than just working with a copy.
    //eg. we draw to the cameraFeed to be displayed in the main() function.
    bool objectDetected = false;
    Mat temp;
    thresholdImage.copyTo(temp);
    //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    //findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );// retrieves all contours
    findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );// retrieves external contours

    //if contours vector is not empty, we have found some objects
    if(contours.size()>0)objectDetected=true;
    else objectDetected = false;

    if(objectDetected){
        //the largest contour is found at the end of the contours vector
        //we will simply assume that the biggest contour is the object we are looking for.
        vector< vector<Point> > largestContourVec;
        largestContourVec.push_back(contours.at(contours.size()-1));
        //make a bounding rectangle around the largest contour then find its centroid
        //this will be the object's final estimated position.
        objectBoundingRectangle = boundingRect(largestContourVec.at(0));
        int xpos = objectBoundingRectangle.x+objectBoundingRectangle.width/2;
        int ypos = objectBoundingRectangle.y+objectBoundingRectangle.height/2;

        //update the objects positions by changing the 'theObject' array values
        theObject[0] = xpos , theObject[1] = ypos;
    }
    //make some temp x and y variables so we dont have to type out so much
    int x = theObject[0];
    int y = theObject[1];

            int maxX = 0, minX = cameraFeed.cols, maxY=0, minY = cameraFeed.rows;

        for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
            for(int j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
            {
                Point p = contours[i][j];

                maxX = max(maxX, p.x);
                minX = min(minX, p.x);

                maxY = max(maxY, p.y);
                minY = min(minY, p.y);
            }
        rectangle(cameraFeed, Point(minX, minY), Point(maxX, maxY), Scalar(0));

        int m = minX + maxX / 4;
        int m2 = minY + maxY / 4;

        double angle;
        angle = atan(m / m2);

        circle(cameraFeed, Point(m, m2), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, 0);
        }

        int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

//some boolean variables for added functionality
    bool objectDetected = false;
    //these two can be toggled by pressing 'd' or 't'
    bool debugMode = false;
    bool trackingEnabled = false;
    bool colordetection=false;
    //set up the matrices that we will need
    //the two frames we will be comparing
    Mat frame1,frame2;
    //their grayscale images (needed for absdiff() function)
    Mat grayImage1,grayImage2;
    //resulting difference image
    Mat differenceImage;
    //thresholded difference image (for use in findContours() function)
    Mat thresholdImage;
    //video capture object.
    VideoCapture capture;

            capture.open(0);

            if (!capture.isOpened()) {
                cout << "ERROR ACQUIRING VIDEO FEED\n";
                getchar();
                return -1;
            }

            while (1) {

                //read first frame
        capture.read(frame1);
        //convert frame1 to gray scale for frame differencing
        cv::cvtColor(frame1,grayImage1,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        //copy second frame
        capture.read(frame2);
        //convert frame2 to gray scale for frame differencing
        cv::cvtColor(frame2,grayImage2,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        //perform frame differencing with the sequential images. This will output an "intensity image"
        //do not confuse this with a threshold image, we will need to perform thresholding afterwards.
        cv::absdiff(grayImage1,grayImage2,differenceImage);
        //threshold intensity image at a given sensitivity value
        cv::threshold(differenceImage,thresholdImage,SENSITIVITY_VALUE,255,THRESH_BINARY);
        if(debugMode==true){
            //show the difference image and threshold image
            cv::imshow("Difference Image",differenceImage);
            cv::imshow("Threshold Image", thresholdImage);
        }else{
            //if not in debug mode, destroy the windows so we don't see them anymore
            cv::destroyWindow("Difference Image");
            cv::destroyWindow("Threshold Image");
        }
        //blur the image to get rid of the noise. This will output an intensity image
        cv::blur(thresholdImage,thresholdImage,cv::Size(BLUR_SIZE,BLUR_SIZE));
        //threshold again to obtain binary image from blur output
        cv::threshold(thresholdImage,thresholdImage,SENSITIVITY_VALUE,255,THRESH_BINARY);
        if(debugMode==true){
            //show the threshold image after it's been "blurred"

            imshow("Final Threshold Image",thresholdImage);

        }
        else {
            //if not in debug mode, destroy the windows so we don't see them anymore
            cv::destroyWindow("Final Threshold Image");
        }

                if (colordetection == true) {
                    //some boolean variables for different functionality within this
                    //program
                    bool trackObjects = true;
                    bool useMorphOps = true;
                    //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
                    Mat cameraFeed;
                    //matrix storage for HSV image
                    Mat HSV;
                    //matrix storage for binary threshold image
                    //x and y values for the location of the object
                    int x = 0, y = 0;
                    //create slider bars for HSV filtering
                    createTrackbars();
                    //start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
                    //all of our operations will be performed within this loop
                    while (1) {
                        //store image to matrix
                        capture.read(cameraFeed);
                        //convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
                        cvtColor(cameraFeed, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
                        //filter HSV image between values and store filtered image to
                        //threshold matrix
                        inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), thresholdImage);
                        //perform morphological operations on thresholded image to eliminate noise
                        //and emphasize the filtered object(s)
                        if (useMorphOps)
                            morphOps(thresholdImage);
                        //pass in thresholded frame to our object tracking function
                        //this function will return the x and y coordinates of the
                        //filtered object
                        if (trackObjects)
                            trackFilteredObject(x, y, thresholdImage, cameraFeed);

                        //show frames 
                        cv::imshow("Thresholded Image", thresholdImage);
                        cv::imshow("HSV Image", HSV);
                        cv::imshow("Original Image", cameraFeed);

                        //delay 30ms so that screen can refresh.
                        //image will not appear without this waitKey() command
                        waitKey(30);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    cv::destroyWindow("Original Image");
                    cv::destroyWindow("HSV Image");
                    cv::destroyWindow("Thresholded Image");
                    cv::destroyWindow("Trackbars");

                }

                if (trackingEnabled) {
                    searchForMovement(thresholdImage, frame1);
                }

                imshow("Frame1", frame1);


                switch (waitKey(10)) {

                case 27: //'esc' key has been pressed, exit program.
                    return 0;
                case 116: //'t' has been pressed. this will toggle tracking
                    trackingEnabled = !trackingEnabled;
                    if (trackingEnabled == false) cout << "Tracking disabled." << endl;
                    else cout << "Tracking enabled." << endl;
                    break;
                case 100: //'d' has been pressed. this will debug mode
                    debugMode = !debugMode;
                    if (debugMode == false) cout << "Debug mode disabled." << endl;
                    else cout << "Debug mode enabled." << endl;
                    break;
                case 112: //'t' has been pressed. this will toggle tracking to color tracking using dilate and erode
                    colordetection = !colordetection;
                    if (colordetection == false) cout << "Tracking not switched" << endl;
                    else {
                        cout << "Tracking switched" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. This doesn't look very minimal.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite **while (1)** loop that you enter when the **colordetection** variable is **true**, so the program never reaches the **switch** statement after you press '**p**' for the first time and switch the value of the **colordetection** variable. Putting **waitKey(30);** at the end of the loop doesn't break out of it - it just waits for the key input, receives it or not, and then ignores it and goes back to the beginning of the loop.

You could put the **switch** statement to a separate function and call this function at the end of the aforementioned loop apart from where you are calling it now.